# How to compile fsharp console application in linux with mutliple modules (how to define order of fs files?)

Tags: linux, f#

How do I compile an fsharp application in linux, using fsharpc from console?

I have multiple modules and my entry point for the application is in a Program.fs file the classic console-application style:

```
open module A
open module B
open module C

[<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv = 
    ...
```

where A, B, C are in files called A.fs, B.fs and C.fs...

In Visual Studio, one can easily define the order to compile to the files in by rearranging them in the project view, however it is not clear to me how to do this in linux...?

I guess I have to define the order in the console somehow

```
$ fsharpc -o test.exe Program.fs --fileorder:[A.fs,B.fs,C.fs,Program.fs]
```

I am using F# 3.1
*(and currently playing around with the new cross platform VSCode IDE)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just pass the files to fsharpc in the correct order:

```
$ fsharpc --out:test.exe A.fs B.fs C.fs Program.fs
```

I usually store this list in a file and then use xargs:

```
$ cat dependency-order.txt
A.fs
B.fs
C.fs
Program.fs
$ cat dependency-order.txt | xargs -d '\n' fsharpc --out:test.exe
```